# Find free node and launch job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two slave node in two different machines, I want to track the node whether it is free to take job or not

e.g. Node A: Some jobs are running on this node.
     Node B: Similarly some jobs are running on this second node.

If job is finished early on Node B and free afterward, then i want to push pending job to Node B (job not executed that is assigned to Node A), so that time can be saved for execution.

First, How can i track the node availability and then how to switch job or push job to execute on another node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scoring+Load+Balancer+plugin you can define node preferences etc.

from the plugin wiki:
*In project configuration pages, "Preference of Node" appears. You can specify scores for nodes or node labels. Multiple preferences can be specified.* - so here you may prioritize node A and node B according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Olia, i would try with this plugin.

Comment: Can I use this in a pipeline?

Comment: I'm using this plugin but facing this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943134/jenkins-build-queue-very-small-jobs-getting-blocked . I see the scores printing for a node is 40 but still it doesn't allow the job to run in that node. I'm not able to figure out a solution for this.